# Symfony3 referencing several entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity A, with several entity B's.  I can display almost everything properly, however, entity B refers to entity C (which refers to entity D).

I want to be able to display the description of C and D, however, I'm unable to wrap my head around how I would achieve this.

So, a simple version of my entities:

```
A

B.description
B.idA
B.idC

C.description
C.idD

D.description
```

In my Controller, I have:

```
public function showAction(A $a)
{
  $aForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\AType', $a);

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $b_all = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:B')->findBy( array('aId' => $a->getId()) );

  return $this->render('a_detail.html.twig', array(
    'a' => $a,
    'b_all' => $b_all,
    'b_count' => count($b_all),
    'aform' => $a->createView(),
  ));
}
```

In my Twig file, I am able to display A, and all B's easy enough by using the built in Twig functions.

```
<div id='aForm'>
  {{ form(aForm) }}
</div>
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="module-tabs">
  {% set tabcount = 0 %}
  {% for b in b_all %}
    <li class="tabs-title {% if tabcount == 0 %}is-active{% endif %}">
      <a href="#panel{{ tabcount }}">{{ b.description }}</a>
    </li>
    {% set tabcount = tabcount + 1 %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="module-tabs" data-equalizer data-equalize-on="large">
  {% set tabcount = 0 %}
  {% for b in b_all %}
    <div class="tabs-panel {% if tabcount == 0 %}is-active{% endif %}" id="panel{{ tabcount }}" data-equalizer-watch>
      {{ b.description }}
      {{ b.idC }} {{ c.description }}
      {{ c.idD }} {{ d.description }}
    </div>
    {% set tabcount = tabcount + 1 %}
  {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

Obviously, I'm not passing in C (or D) into my Twig file, however, I would like to display the description instead of the ID of C (along with the description of D).

My first thought, would be to use a leftJoin, in a custom repository function for B.  But I'm not sure how to resolve the same column names in Symfony/Doctrine.

Comment: If you have properly configured relations in Doctrine mapping, then you can access child entities by using getters. Related entities will be automatically lazy loaded. You should stop thinking about database and work with objects instead. Doctrine can be almost transparent in this matter.

Comment: In particular, b.c.d.description should work in twig.

Comment: @dragoste Ok, I believe I understand what you're saying.  Basically, setup the OneToMany and OneToOne mappings in my entities properly, and then the framework magic will happen.

Comment: Yes. Actually it's Doctrine ORM's *magic*, not framework's ;-)

Comment: Notice that you probably need to review your Data Model completly (analyse of your project) because when you do that you'll more likely have simple relationship (at least a->b or in worse case a->b->c) that give you simple task when coding your project